# Python: Iterar en un for y obtener cuantas objetos en la lista

Tags: python

Tengo una lista con productos manzanas y peras y quiero imprimir por pantalla cuántas manzanas hay mediante un `if` pero solamente me imprime el "no hay manzanas". ¿Dónde está el error y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Éste es mi código:

```
p = ["manzana_00", "manzana_01", "manzana_02",
     "pera_00", "pera_01", "pera_03"]

for i in p:

    if i == "manzana_*":
        print i + " es manzana"

    else:
        print "nada hay manzanas"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que tal y como estás haciendo ahora la comparación, estás buscando que la cadena `i` sea exactamente igual a "manzana_*" que no se cumple para ningún elemento de la lista. Lo que podrías hacer es comprobar si el elemento de la lista contiene la cadena "manzana_" usando `in`.

Eso se realizaría de la siguiente forma:

```
p = ["manzana_00", "manzana_01", "manzana_02",
     "pera_00", "pera_01", "pera_03"]

for i in p:

    if "manzana_" in i:
        print i + " es manzana"

    else:
        print "nada hay manzanas"
```

Y ahora el resultado que obtendrías es el siguiente:

> manzana_00 es manzana
>
> manzana_01 es manzana
>
> manzana_02 es manzana
>
> nada hay manzanas
>
> nada hay manzanas
>
> nada hay manzanas

Puedes ver como funciona en este [Python Fiddl](http://pythonfiddle.com/respuesta-para-soes)e.

Comment: Gracias Alvaro , funciono